# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol for Inner Class

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android, and I have one class in a file named WeatherContract.java which has a static inner class which is as follows:

```
public class WeatherContract {
...
...
    public static final class WeatherEntry implements BaseColumns {
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to call the inner class in another file called TestWeatherContract.java as follows

```
...
import com.example.android.sunshine.app.data.WeatherContract;
...

public class TestWeatherContract extends AndroidTestCase {
...
    public void testBuildWeatherLocation() {
        Uri locationUri = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocation(TEST_WEATHER_LOCATION);
...
```

Now in the following line, the word "WeatherEntry" is marked in red and when I hover on the word I get the following error "Cannot resolve symbol 'WeatherEntry'.

```
Uri locationUri = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocation(TEST_WEATHER_LOCATION);
```

Please note that I am not getting any error in the import statement, so I'm assuming that there are no errors in stating the path of the class.

Also, I have another file called FetchWeatherTask.java. I have the following import statement at the beginning of the file:

```
import com.example.android.sunshine.app.data.WeatherContract.WeatherEntry;
```

In this case, in the import statement again the word "WeatherEntry" is marked in red and I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'WeatherEntry'".

Please help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code for this class that's trying to use WeatherEntry and getting an error. Point out exactly what the error says and what line of code it refers to.

Comment: @Kenster Thank you for your suggestions. I have edited my post to make it more descriptive. Please let me know if I need to add any further information.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the static inner class

```
WeatherContract.WeatherEntry ob = new WeatherContract.WeatherEntry();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check again bro.

Checked. Its working fine. Using Android Studio 1.5.1

```
public class C {
A.B obj=new A.B();
}
```

:

```
public class A {

public static final class B implements BaseColumns{
}
}
```

Comment: I've edited my post to show where the error is occuring. Can you please go through it again and help me. Thanks